# How to assign a single static source IP address for all pods of a service or deployment in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, openshift

Consider a microservice `X` which is containerized and deployed in a kubernetes cluster. `X` communicates with a Payment Gateway `PG`. However, the payment gateway requires a static IP for services contacting it as it maintains a whitelist of IP addresses which are authorized to access the payment gateway. One way for `X` to contact `PG` is through a third party proxy server like `QuotaGuard` which will provide a static IP address to service `X` which can be whitelisted by the Payment Gateway. 
However, is there an inbuilt mechanism in kubernetes which can enable a service deployed in a kube-cluster to obtain a static IP address?

Comment: While waiting for builds and deployments during last few days, I've polished my old VIP-iptables scripts that I used to use as a replacement for external load-balancers on bare-metal clusters, so now they can be used as well to provide egress VIPs as described in the last point of my answer. You can give them a try: https://github.com/morgwai/kevip

Answer (score 2):

there's no mechanism in Kubernetes for this yet.

other possible solutions:

- if nodes of the cluster are in a private network behind a NAT then just add your network's default gateway to the PG's whitelist.
- if whitelist can accept a cidr apart from single IPs (like `86.34.0.0/24` for example) then add your cluster's network cidr to the whitelist

If every node of the cluster has a public IP and you can't add a cidr to the whitelist then it gets more complicated:

- a naive way would be to add ever node's IP to the whitelist, but it doesn't scale above tiny clusters few just few nodes.
- if you have access to administrating your network, then even though nodes have pubic IPs, you can setup a NAT for the network anyway that targets only packets with PG's IP as a destination.
- if you don't have administrative access to the network, then another way is to allocate a machine with a static IP somewhere and make it act as a proxy using iptables NAT similarly like above again. This introduces a single point of failure though. In order to make it highly available, you could deploy it on a kubernetes cluster again with few (2-3) replicas (this can be the same cluster where X is running: see below). The replicas instead of using their node's IP to communicate with PG would share a VIP using [keepalived](https://www.keepalived.org/) that would be added to PG's whitelist. (you can have a look at [easy-keepalived](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/92xhum/easykeepalived_simple_load_balancing_for/) and either try to use it directly or learn from it how it does things). This requires high privileges on the cluster: you need be able to grant to pods of your proxy `NET_ADMIN` and `NET_RAW` capabilities in order for them to be able to add iptables rules and setup a VIP.

**update:**

While waiting for builds and deployments during last few days, I've polished my old VIP-iptables scripts that I used to use as a replacement for external load-balancers on bare-metal clusters, so now they can be used as well to provide egress VIP as described in the last point of my original answer. You can give them a try: https://github.com/morgwai/kevip

Answer (score -1):

There are two answers to this question: for the pod IP itself, it depends on your CNI plugin. Some allow it with special pod annotations. However most CNI plugins also involve a NAT when talking to the internet so the pod IP being static on the internal network is kind of moot, what you care about is the public IP the connection ends up coming from. So the second answer is "it depends on how your node networking and NAT is set up". This is usually up to the tool you used to deploy Kubernetes (or OpenShift in your case I guess). With Kops it's pretty easy to tweak the VPC routing table.